# EmberJS Handle Bars Inputs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have the following:

```
         <span>{{m.search_type}}</span>
          {{input value=m.search_type}}
```

I retrieve the `search_type` with

`this.get(search_type)` in the controller that handles the form submission.

However, when I change the input value, the value within the `<span>..</span>` will change. This is the defined behavior in the docs.

I want the span to be the title for the input field and to not change along with the value of `search_type`. Search type is dynamic so I can't just hardcode the value for `{{m.search_type}}`.

Is there a way to do this? I tried creating a `EmberJS Helper` to map the value to a new string but this still changes whenever `search_type` changes.

Comment: What is `m`? Could you post how and where you define `m`, please.

Comment: `m` is an object passed through the a route's `models:`. It is an object with a field `search_type`. (To be more specific `models:` returns a list of `m`s.

Answer (score 2):

Properties are always bound by default. Use the `unbound` helper to unbind the property.

```
<span>{{unbound m.search_type}}</span>

{{input value=m.search_type}}
```